# Use Macaulay2 to show that a quotient ring is a field

Tags: abstract, macaulay2

I am new to Macaulay2. I tried to use the following command to show that a quotient ring S=ZZ_977[x]/<7x^11+4x^5-23x^4+x-27> is a field:

```
i2 : S = ZZ[x]/<7*x^11+4*x^5-23*x^4+x-27>
o2 = S
     IsField S
```

But it doesn't work. I looked it up on internet but they don't cover this part. Can someone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The command (or method in M2 speak) you're looking for is `isField` rather than `IsField`.

> i1 : R = ZZ[x];
>
> i2 : I = ideal(7*x^11+4*x^5-23*x^4+x-27);
>
> o2 : Ideal of R
>
> i3 : S = R/I;
>
> i4 : isField S
>
> o4 = false
>
> i5 : isField (ZZ/2)
>
> o5 = true

But there is (or at least was as of February 2014) a [major caveat](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/macaulay2/fMed1ROShv4) about using this internal M2 method for testing whether a quotient ring is a field (alternately testing the maximality of the ideal).

More generally, the applicable rules from the [Macaulay2 style guide](https://github.com/Macaulay2/M2/wiki/Package-Writing-Style-Guide) for naming methods and variables are

> Names representing methods must be verbs and written in mixed case
>   starting with lower case.
>
> The prefix "is" should be used for Boolean variables and methods.